# What is the most reliable way to get Last Insert Id when inserting into mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I have found two way to get the last insert id

```
Result, err := s.DB.ExecContext(ctx, query, qp)
if err != nil {
    return 0, err
}
ID, err := Result.LastInsertId()
```

and another way is to use mysql's

```
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

How different are these two methods and what should i do in-case the first method throws an error, would it mean my insert failed or would it mean just that method failed to return the id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Result.LastInsertId()`. This is always reliable.

Doing your own `SELECT` is not reliable, due to the way the Go driver handles pools of connection. If you do, say:

```
INSERT foo INTO bar ...
```

in one statement, then later:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

in another statement, you may get different connections to the database for each statement.

This means your manually-selected ID may correspond with some completely unrelated INSERT statement which just happened to occur on that same connection in the past, or you may get nothing at all.

Comment: @lord-commander, note that the server actually tells the client the last insert ID in each result set it sends [see for yourself](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/8056f2ca4aa7be2e2e10ab01426a630d5a5bfa81/packets.go#L611), so indeed this information is the best you can get even per the protocol spec.